# sending and receiving udp packets on same port

Tags: c++, c, windows, udp, winsock

i need my client app to be able to sendto() and recvfrom() through the same port using UDP.

I have discovered i can only bind one socket to the port and it's better to do it when using recvfrom(), otherwise things mess up.

I want to be able to still send UDP packets through that port but binding it to a different socket is a problem as i mentioned above.

What can i do ?

thanks.

Comment: by the way, now that i think about it, i can use sendto() and recvfrom() on the same socket. since i am sending and receiving on different threads is this considered safe thing to do ? thanks

Comment: Yes. It's the correct way to do it. You may need to synchronize access, though.

Comment: Did you try using the same socket?  What got messed up?  Can you post some minimal code showing where you had an issue?

Comment: as you already figured out, you can use the same socket handle for sending and receiving.  There is no issues with using this handle from multiple threads.  OS will take care of internal synchronization, but if you have shared data, that obviously will have to be protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine.  One socket bound to a port where you use recvfrom() and sendto() on the same socket.  See this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN that shows recvfrom() in isolation - right around the recvfrom() you should be able to sendto() using that same socket.

Comment: i've confirmed that using the same socket for sending and receiving works just fine.